# how to add line break after a specified character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a line break in the following string example which is displayed in a div. The line break would be right after the pipe symbol.

Comment: Are you wanting an HTML line break or a JS string line break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your div is called "MyDiv", for example, do this

```
function MyFunction()
{
   var DIV_CHECK = document.getElementById("MyDiv");
   var DIV_OUTPUT = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < DIV_CHECK.innerHTML.length; ++i)
   {
       if(DIV_CHECK.innerHTML[i] == "~")
       {
          DIV_OUTPUT += "<br>";
       }
       else
       {
          DIV_OUTPUT += DIV_CHECK.innerHTML[i];
       }
   }
   DIV_CHECK.innerHTML = DIV_OUTPUT;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

use String.replace method like this:

```
your_div.innerHTML = your_div.innerHTML.replace(/\|/g,"|<br>");
```

`/\|/g` - is a regular expression, which means catch every pipe symbol in a string (g means search globally), you use it as first argument to 'replace' function, so it replaces matched symbols with string in second argument.

Comment: You need to escape that pipe, or regex will treat it like an "or" and you'll get weird results.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something:

`bARM & iARM-DI Water Inlet Fitting ~ 1 ~ ewa ~ eaqa ~ 2 |<br /> bARM & iARM-DI Water Inlet Fitting ~ 1 ~ ewa ~ eaqa ~ 2`

Note the `<br />` after the pipe. If you need to do it using JavaScript, Bogdan's answer works, but just html is better, as long as that's an option.